# How to convert formula from SSRS to Power BI

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

Now I am in the task of passing some reports that are in SQL Server Reporting Services to Power BI, among them I find a report which apparently obtains the average of a value as follows:

```
=Format(AVG(Fields!t_TOTAL_SALIDA_seg.Value)/3600, "##") + ":" + Format(AVG(Fields!t_TOTAL_SALIDA_seg.Value) MOD 60, "##")
```

I have tried to pass this same formula to Power BI as follows:

```
= AVERAGE(Consulta1[t_TOTAL_SALIDA_seg])/3600 + AVERAGE(Consulta1[t_TOTAL_SALIDA_seg])
```

But its values ​​do not correspond to the report found in SSRS, I do not know if it is necessary to add something else to my formula or change something, I hope someone can give me guidance.

**UPDATE:**

I have made use of the formula that they tell me in one of the answers as follows:

```
= FORMAT( AVERAGE(Consulta1[t_TOTAL_SALIDA_seg])/3600 , "##" ) + ":" + FORMAT( AVERAGE(Consulta1[t_TOTAL_SALIDA_seg]), "##" )
```

But I got an error message after saving the formula

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**

I am comparing the results in the SSRS and Power BI report but their results do not match, the following are the values ​​in SSRS:

[image]

And these are the results in Power BI after correcting the formula:

[image]

Their results are close but they do not match anyway.

I would like to think why I still need to add `MOD 60` to my Power BI formula as the report in SSRS brings it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you try to convert a range of second in the average but converted in format hours/seconds.

For example, if you have 3 records : [image]

You will get 13:32 if you respect the format ## for the Number and the mod60.

So if you want to reproduce the same in PowerBI you need to cast something like that :

= FORMAT( AVERAGE(Consulta1[t_TOTAL_SALIDA_seg])/3600 , "##" )  & ":" & FORMAT( MOD(AVERAGE(Consulta1[t_TOTAL_SALIDA_seg]),60), "##" )

Comment: When using the formula that you show me in the answer, I get an error message added in my last update

Comment: @user11804298 - it sounds like you'll need to explicitly convert the numbers to text - ugh, kinda lame. Maybe if you use an `&` instead of `+` for text?

Comment: @HannoverFist Where I use `MOD 60` in the Power BI formula, I say it because in the SSRS if I use it

Comment: @HannoverFist 
Now it no longer generates the error but the data does not match. I would like to think that it is due to the `MOD 60`, any other suggestions?

Comment: If you are trying to convert seconds then I'm not sure your original SSRS expression was correct as there is no accounting for the number of minutes. If you only wanted hours and seconds then you would need to use mod with 3600 not 60. Might be worth checking what the original report was supposed to be showing.